# Do we have web services APIs to fetch the id of folders by specifying the name of the folders?

Tags: box-api

I am using the Box APIs available for performing different box operations. I am having a problem in designing a user friendly UI for configuring connections with box, such that we can specify the folder's name and upload our files to this desired folder. I found an API which helps us put files into folders by specifying their id, but not by their name. Please let me know if this is possible? If this is not possible, it would make it very tough for users to specify where they want to upload their files.

Answer (score 1):

The current way to achieve this type of functionality is to navigate down the hierarchy step by step. (basically to crawl the tree) using this API call: http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-get-information-about-a-folder

This call will give you the "item_collection" for the current folder including the ID's of all subfolders:

```
"item_collection":
{
    "total_count":2,
    "entries":[
        {
            "type":"file",
            "id":"2305649799",
            "sequence_id":"1",
            "name":"testing.html"
        },
        {
            "type":"folder",
            "id":"2305623799",
            "sequence_id":"1",
            "name":"a child folder"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can progressively recurse down from the root folder.  The main trick is to know that the root folder for a user will always have an ID of 0, so that gives you your starting point.

e.g. in this example if you were looking for a folder

> /a child folder/something else

your calls would be:

https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0 (for the root folder)

https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/2305623799 (for 'a child folder')

This is the most common interface for cloud storage API's.  The only exception I can think of right now is Dropbox, whose API works in terms of paths.